# C18 compiler typedef enum data size

Tags: enums, size, microchip

I'm trying to port code over to compile using Microchip's C18 compiler for a PIC microcontroller.  The code includes enums with large values assigned (>8-bit).  They are not working properly, indicating that, for example, 0x02 is the same as 0x2002.

How can I force the enumerated values to be referenced as 16-bit values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

For future reference, the C18 compiler will NOT promote variables OR constants when performing a math operation, even though it is ANSI C standard.  This is to increase speed while running on 8-bit processors.

To force ANSI compliance, use the "-Oi" compiler option.

[See page 92 of the C18 manual.](http://www.microchip.com/Microchip.WWW.SecureSoftwareList/secsoftwaredownload.aspx?device=en010014&lang=en&ReturnURL=http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en010014#)

Answer (score 1):

In the DirectX headers, every enum has a `FORCE_DWORD` value in it with a value of `0xffffffff`. I guess that's basically what you want, it forces to compiler to let the enum have *at least* 32 bits. So try adding a `FORCE_WORD` with a value of `0xffff`.

This won't solve your problem, of course, if that compiler just does not support enums greater than 8 bits.